# Lmer for longitudinal design

Tags: r, lme4, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal dataset where I have the following variables for each subject:

IV: 3 factors (`factorA`, `factorB`, `factorC`, `factorD`), each measured twice, at the beginning and at the end of an intervention.

DV: one outcome variable (behavior), also measure twice, at the beginning and at the end of the intervention.

I would like to create a model that uses the **change in factorA, factorB, factorC, factorD** (change from beginning to end of the intervention) to predict the **change in behavior** (again from beginning to end).

I thought to use the delta values of `factorA`, `factorB`, `factorC`, `factorD` (from pre to post intervention) and use these delta values to predict the delta values of `D1`. I would also like to covary-out the absolute values of each factor (`A`, `B`, `C` and `D`) (e.g. using only the value at the beginning of the intervention for each factor) to make sure I account for the change that the absolute values (rather than the change) of these IVs may have on the DV.

Here is my dataset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LneoK.png)

Here is my model so far:

```
Model <- lmer(Delta_behavior ~ Absolute_factorA + Absolute_factorB + 
              Absolute_factorC + Absolute_factorD + Delta_factorA + 
              Delta_factorB + Delta_factorC + Delta_factorD + 
              (1|Subject),a)
```

I think I am doing something wrong because I get this error:

> Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations

What am I doing wrong? Is the data set structured weirdly? Should I not use the delta values? Should I use another test (not `lmer`)?

Comment: can you please show your data **not** as a screenshot/image, but by either using `dput()` or by cutting and pasting text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have reduced your data to a single observation per subject, you don't need to use a multi-level/mixed model. The reason that `lmer` is giving you an error is that in this situation the between-subject variance is confounded with the residual variance.

You can probably go ahead and use a linear model (`lm`) for this analysis.

### More technical detail

The equation for the distribution of the `i`th observation is something like `[fixed-effect predictors] + eps(subject(i)) + eps(i)` where `eps(subject(i))` is the Normal error term of the subject associated with the `i`th observation, and `eps(i)` is the Normal residual error associated with the `i`th observation. If we only have one observation per subject, then each observation has two error terms that are unique to it. The sum of two Normal variables with zero means and variances of V1 and V2 is also Normal with mean zero and variance V1+V2 ... therefore V1 and V2 are *jointly unidentifiable*. You can use `lmerControl` to override the error if you really want to; `lmer` will return some arbitrary combination of `V1`, `V2` estimates that sum to the total variance.

There's a similar example illustrated [here](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/classes/uqam/mixedlab1.html).

Comment: if this solved your problem, you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it

Comment: Hi Ben, I actually have one more question, see belo... thank you!